# Want to timestamp two files

Tags: python, mysql, django, timestamp, gzip

I have two lines in my views.py file.

**views.py**

```
os.popen3("mysqldump -u *username* -p*password* *database* > /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.sql")
os.popen3("gzip -c /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.sql > /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.gz"
```

I want to be able to do is in each of these files `backup.sql` and `backup.gz` I want them to be timestamped. So this means I want to see the date in the name of these files. For example, file name  `backup-16-Aug-2011.gz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from datetime import datetime

# yes, this is me being lazy and not wanting to write a format string.
date = datetime.today().isoformat().split('T')[0]

mysql = "mysqldump -u *username* -p*password* *database* > /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup-{}.sql".format(date)
gzip = "gzip -c /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.sql > /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup-{}.gz".format(date)

Popen(mysql, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell = True)
Popen(gzip, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell = True)
```

or, for old versions of Python,

```
from datetime import datetime
import os

date = datetime.today().isoformat().split('T')[0]

mysql = "mysqldump -u *username* -p*password* *database* > /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup-%s.sql" % date
gzip = "gzip -c /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.sql > /usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup-%s.gz" % date

os.popen3(mysql)
os.popen3(gzip)
```